# Active Directory users showing inactive users after hosting on iis server, while debugging it shows Active users only

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, iis-7

I have a .Net web application that has a page which displays Active users from Active Directory. In local machine while debugging it displays only active users whereas the same code when hosted on windows server iis, it displays even inactive users. Code and configuration file remains the same. Can someone please help me with this?

The users count should be the same irrespective of environment.

Comment: Talk to your domain administrators, as they can show you further why the same code (LDAP queries) can yield different results when the actual accounts differ, https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: You will have to show some code before anyone could help you. Does it display a list of all active users? If so, how does it get that list? What LDAP query is used? Is the query stored in the web.config file that is different locally and on the server?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: We use query like ldap://something.com/OU=@OU,OU=Users,DC=SomeDC. This is the sample query. Sorry I won't be able to provide exact query due to security issues

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between debug mode and IIS is using the different identity.
You can find which user account is being used when debuging and set the same identity in IIS.
Output this variable to see current user:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```